# Error Occurred when trying to access support.microsoft.com pages

Tags: website

I'm trying to access the [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com) website looking for help for a technical issue, and when I click on "Contact Answer Desk" I'm getting an Infinite Loop message, and when I click on "All Products" in the home page, I'm getting an Error Occurred message.

Anybody else having the same problem? Any workarounds to reach the Contact Answer Desk ?

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post this question, I would need guidance to where to put it if it's not. I'm just looking for support for the microsoft support.

EDIT:

Result to direct access to "support.microsoft.com/en-us/allproducts"
[image]

Comment: What you're describing could be just web site problems.  However, I recently had some strange problems with most Microsoft sites, including that.  Deleting all Microsoft-related cookies triggered some kind of reset that fixed them all.

Comment: Works here (after signing in with my microsoft account) - I get a "popup window" on the right with more choices.

Comment: @fixer1234, thank you for your reply. I tried doing that, I can't quite say that it fixed it, because one time it works but when retrying it does the same error. Also it seems that i need to manually add "/en-us" to the support.microsoft.com website because otherwise i would get an Infinite Loop error.

Comment: Try going direct to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/allproducts

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried that but still same problem. I updated the question with the screenshot of the result

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @DavidPostill I only cleared the cookies for the microsoft support website, because i'm currently unable to clear all browsing data. However, i tried using Internet Explorer and I finally could see that Popup window. So I guess I will be using it instead of Chrome (currently showing the errors).

Comment: Works here in Chrome. But it  is the first time I've ever been to http://support.microsoft.com/ (I normally use Firefox, I rarely us Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround the problem by using a different browser (Internet Explorer instead of Chrome).

However, if you face the same problem, fixer1234 and DavidPostill suggestion from the comments above is to delete the browsing cache or delete the microsoft-related cookies and that would probably work for you.